# How to read a list of dicts from a txt file?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, txt

I would like to read this txt file and get a list of dictionaries in python:

*data.txt:*

`[{"name": "Aaron", "age": "1"}, {"name": "Bruce", "age": "2"}]`

Whereas:

```
with open('data.txt','r') as f:
    list_of_dict = f.read()
```

```
print(list_of_dict[0])
```

***Prints** --> {"name": "Aaron", "age": "1"}*

```
print(list_of_dict[1])
```

***Prints** --> {"name": "Bruce", "age": "2"}*

```
print(type(list_of_dict[1])
```

***Prints** --> dict*

```
print(type(list_of_dict)
```

**Prints** --> list

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `json.load(file)` instead of `file.read()`

```
import json
with open("a.txt", encoding="UTF8") as f:
    a = json.load(f)

print(type(a)) # <class 'list'>
print(a[0])
print(a[1])
```

document: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Answer (score 1):

Try using `json` module:

```py
import json

with open("data.txt", "r") as f_in:
    list_of_dict = json.load(f_in)

print(list_of_dict[0])
print(list_of_dict[1])
print(type(list_of_dict[1]))
print(type(list_of_dict))
```

Prints:

```
{'name': 'Aaron', 'age': '1'}
{'name': 'Bruce', 'age': '2'}
<class 'dict'>
<class 'list'>
```